# automatically calculate the number of legal leaves of an employee in HR module of Odoo v10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have installed the HR module in Odoo 10 with the leaves option.
I can create new leaves and assign them to employees, but I wanted to know if there is a way of making that task dynamic.

For example, for every complete month of work( 35hr x 4 weeks ), I would like the employee to have 2 days of legal holidays.

And if he doesn't take them, they keep accumulating .

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what base you want to calculate that. You can depend it on a value on the user/employee, on contract working hours or on timesheets. You have to create the business logic by yourself or/and can ask with your ideas (code) here. Nobody will answer this question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a trigger or cron job which will execute every month.
but you have to uncheck allow override limit of holiday_status of only one type of holiday for example in your case legal leaves, and for all others you have to check allow override limit for them , because the default odoo holiday module work like that it's associate reamining_leaves to only one holiday type you can change it if you want

there is a field named remaining_leaves in hr module Employee class you can add the value you want to increase with.